# What is the important of the use of codeigniter database session (ci_session)

Tags: database, codeigniter, session

I need an answer from someone who have an experience with using codeigniter session. In config file i have to don't use session database because it cause a conflit in my code :

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

I use here session database off :

```
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
```

What's is the importante of using this? and may i have problems in security if i desactivate it (FALSE) ?

Comment: Because it stores the userdata of sessions in database else you can not use sessions in codeigniter 2.2.1 codeigniter 3 when done uses files and also database you have more option in codeigniter 3 when using sessions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from codeigniter you can read more here
http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html
[image: this is from codeigniter you can read more here.]

Comment: Please note that BCIT is now looking after codeigniter not Ellislab not supporting codeigniter. BCIT http://www.codeigniter.com/ is.